# How to attach bootstrap 5 .is-invalid to Angulars ng-invalid?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, bootstrap-5

Bootstrap 5 has a class to mark input fields as invalid (.is-invalid).

[image]

I'm using a reactive form and when my input is "invalid" the "ng-invalid" style is added. **Is there a way to change this style to .is-invalid to match the Bootstrap class?**

html form:

```
<div class="mb-3">
  <label for="lastNameInput" class="form-label">Achternaam</label>
  <input
    formControlName="lastName"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    id="lastNameInput"
  />
</div>
```

In typescript I created my form:

```
this.membersForm = this.fb.group({
  name: new UntypedFormControl('', Validators.required),
  lastName: new UntypedFormControl('', Validators.required),
```

Answer (score 1):

just "duplicate" the class

```
.form-control.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
  border-color: #dc3545;
  padding-right: calc(1.5em + .75rem);
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 12 12' width='12' height='12' fill='none' stroke='%23dc3545'%3e%3ccircle cx='6' cy='6' r='4.5'/%3e%3cpath stroke-linejoin='round' d='M5.8 3.6h.4L6 6.5z'/%3e%3ccircle cx='6' cy='8.2' r='.6' fill='%23dc3545' stroke='none'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right calc(.375em + .1875rem) center;
  background-size: calc(.75em + .375rem) calc(.75em + .375rem);
}
.form-control.ng-invalid.ng-touched:focus,.form-check-input.ng-invalid.ng-touched:focus{
  border-color: #dc3545;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem rgba(220,53,69,.25);
}
.form-check-input.ng-invalid.ng-touched
{
  border-color: #dc3545;
}
.ng-invalid.ng-touched ~ .form-check-label
{
  color:#dc3545
}
.ng-invalid.ng-touched ~ .invalid-feedback
{
  display: block;
}
```

e.g.

```
 <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="lastNameInput" class="form-label">Achternaam</label>
    <input
      [formControl]="lastName"
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      id="lastNameInput"
    />
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide a valid city.</div>
  </div>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xndnmf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fstyles.css)